Creation of Tkinter exe using nuitka opens and closes without feedback. App works perfectly when running in python environment
When I apply the main loop solution, I still have the same problem. The script works perfectly when running the .py script. So the exe is created with the nuitka, and when I run the exe the console opens for a few seconds, and then closes, but nothing happens. I also opened the exe using cmd, but it just completes without any output. Can someone try to create sample app and test this? Or maybe you already c the solution when looking at the code. You need a few pdf files and a XLS sheet in a folder called "Project Fluvius" on the user's desktop.
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import getmac  # For MAC address check
import requests  # To fetch online time
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from tkinter import Tk, simpledialog, messagebox
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys  # Needed for sys.exit(1)
import traceback  # For logging errors

# Log file setup
log_file = open("error_log.txt", "w")
sys.stdout = log_file
sys.stderr = log_file

# Define paths and global variables
desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
project_folder = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'Project XXXXXX')
pdf_folder_path = project_folder  # Assuming PDFs are in 'Project XXXXXX' folder
master_file_path = os.path.join(project_folder, 'lege meetstaat.1.xls')
output_pdf_path = os.path.join(project_folder, 'pdf_totals_output.pdf')
timestamp_file = os.path.join(project_folder, 'timestamp.txt')  # Store first run date here

TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS = 90  # 90 days trial
AUTHORIZED_MAC_ADDRESS = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"  # Update MAC address

# Functions
def get_mac_address():
    """Get MAC address of current machine."""
    mac_address = getmac.get_mac_address()
    print(f"Detected MAC Address: {mac_address}")
    return mac_address

def check_mac_address():
    """Ensure the current machine is authorized by MAC address."""
    print("MAC address check")
    mac_address = get_mac_address()
    if mac_address != AUTHORIZED_MAC_ADDRESS:
        print(f"Unauthorized device. Access denied. Current MAC Address: {mac_address}")
        messagebox.showerror("Unauthorized Access", "This device is not authorized to use this application.")
        sys.exit(1)

def get_online_time():
    """Fetch the current time from an online API."""
    try:
        print("Fetching online time")
        response = requests.get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            online_time = response.json()['datetime']
            print(f"Fetched online time: {online_time}")
            return datetime.strptime(online_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z").replace(tzinfo=None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching online time: {e}")
        return None  # If online time is not available, return None

def store_first_run_date(first_run_date):
    """Store the first run date in a file."""
    with open(timestamp_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(first_run_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    print(f"First run date stored: {first_run_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")

def load_first_run_date():
    """Load the first run date from the file."""
    if os.path.exists(timestamp_file):
        with open(timestamp_file, 'r') as f:
            date_str = f.read().strip()
            print(f"First run date loaded: {date_str}")
            return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print("No first run date found.")
    return None

def check_trial_period():
    """Ensure the trial period has not expired."""
    print("Trial period check")
    first_run_date = load_first_run_date()
    current_time = get_online_time() or datetime.now()

    if first_run_date is None:
        first_run_date = current_time
        store_first_run_date(first_run_date)
    else:
        days_since_first_run = (current_time - first_run_date).days
        print(f"Days since first run: {days_since_first_run}")

        if days_since_first_run > TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS:
            root = Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            messagebox.showinfo("Subscription Expired", "Your subscription has expired. Please extend your license.")
            sys.exit(1)

def try_remove_output_pdf():
    """Remove existing PDF if it exists."""
    print("Checking for existing PDF output")
    if os.path.exists(output_pdf_path):
        try:
            os.remove(output_pdf_path)
            print(f"Removed existing PDF output: {output_pdf_path}")
        except PermissionError:
            root = Tk()
            root.withdraw()
            messagebox.showerror("File In Use", f"Please close the file '{output_pdf_path}' and try again.")
            raise

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    """Extract text from a PDF file."""
    print(f"Extracting text from PDF: {pdf_path}")
    text = ""
    try:
        with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
            for page in range(len(reader.pages)):
                text += reader.pages[page].extract_text()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading {pdf_path}: {e}")
    return text

def find_codes_in_pdf_text(pdf_text):
    """Find relevant codes in the extracted PDF text."""
    return re.findall(r'\b3\d{6}\b|\b3\d{8}\b', pdf_text)

def calculate_total_from_codes(codes, master_data, coefficient):
    """Calculate the total price from the found codes."""
    print("Calculating total from codes")
    total = 0.0
    fixed_coefficient_codes = ['3003597', '3003869', '3003868']

    for code in codes:
        code = str(code.strip())
        if code in master_data['Code'].values:
            price = master_data.loc[master_data['Code'] == code, 'Price'].values[0]
            if code in fixed_coefficient_codes:
                total += price
            else:
                total += price * coefficient
    return total

def get_calculation_coefficient():
    """Get the coefficient from user input."""
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    coefficient = simpledialog.askfloat("Input", "Enter the Calculation Coefficient:")
    return coefficient if coefficient else 1  # Default to 1 if nothing is entered

def generate_pdf(pdf_totals, output_pdf_path):
    """Generate the output PDF."""
    print("Generating PDF output")
    c = canvas.Canvas(output_pdf_path, pagesize=A4)
    width, height = A4
    
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 16)
    c.drawCentredString(width / 2, height - 50, "Fluvius totaal meetstaat")
    c.line(width / 2 - 100, height - 60, width / 2 + 100, height - 60)
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 12)

    line_height = 15
    margin_left = 40
    margin_right = width - 40
    total_sum = 0.0
    y_position = height - 100

    for pdf_file, total in pdf_totals.items():
        pdf_title = os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0]
        total_sum += total
        c.drawString(margin_left, y_position, pdf_title)
        c.drawRightString(margin_right, y_position, f"€{total:.2f}")
        y_position -= line_height

    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 12)
    c.drawCentredString(width / 2, y_position - 20, f"Totaal van meetstaten: €{total_sum:.2f}")
    c.showPage()
    c.save()

# Main function to organize the code execution
def main():
    try:
        # Print statements for checking where the execution reaches
        print("Start of the script")
        
        # Load master data
        master_data = pd.read_excel(master_file_path, sheet_name='Grondw')
        master_data = master_data.iloc[:, [1, 25]]
        master_data.columns = ['Code', 'Price']
        master_data['Code'] = master_data['Code'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\.0$', '', regex=True).str.strip()

        check_mac_address()
        check_trial_period()
        try_remove_output_pdf()

        pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path) if f.endswith('.pdf') and f != os.path.basename(output_pdf_path)]
        pdf_totals = {}
        coefficient = get_calculation_coefficient()

        for pdf_file in pdf_files:
            pdf_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, pdf_file)
            pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
            codes = find_codes_in_pdf_text(pdf_text)
            total = calculate_total_from_codes(codes, master_data, coefficient)
            pdf_totals[pdf_file] = total

        generate_pdf(pdf_totals, output_pdf_path)
        print(f"PDF report generated: {output_pdf_path}")

    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc(file=log_file)
        sys.exit(1)
    
    finally:
        log_file.close()

# Entry point of the script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    main_window.mainloop()


Don't run it by double-click. Open console and run it from command line to see the error you get

Hello Buran, thank you for your quick reply but i already tried and mentioned your solution in the explanation of the problem. Thank you for your time!

You redirect both sys.stdout and sys.stderr, and also print the possible traceback in Except block,  to log file. What's the content of  the log file after execution?

There are no log files generated. The folder only contains the exe and other compiling data. It should generate one everytime i run the exe but nothing...

main_window is not defined anywhere. How do you manage to run it? Additional note: There should be only one root window (tk.Tk). Tkinter simpledialog and messagebox work without creating root in each function.

The EXE is still not running even after changing the script to work with a main window which was not really nescesarry. So i repeat the scripts and many adaptations on the script work but the exe generated with py-to-exe or nuitka do not work

Hello guys, So i found the solution myself but i would like to thank you all for your energy. I already had Anaconda installed but the virtual machine was creating problems and overruling the normal python installation which caused confusion with the installed libraries. I just formated my laptop and freshly installed python only and now everything is working. Conclusion: dont install to many environments that create and manage different libraries but also at the same time. Have a dedicated machine for convertion of py to exe and a dedicated machine to develop using many libraries and resource
